# Unexpected Apache Beam (Dataframe API) behavior gives tuples instead of dictionaries, breaking BigQuery upload

Tags: python, dataframe, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Learning Apache Beam with the dataframe API at the moment and coming across some unexpected behavior that I was hoping an expert could explain to me.

Here's the simplest version of my issue I could drill it down to (in the real version the dataframe transform is something more complex):

```
class LocationRow(NamedTuple):
  h3_index: str

with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
  (pipeline 
    | ReadFromBigQuery(
        query=f'SELECT h3_index FROM {H3_INDEX_TABLE} LIMIT 100', use_standard_sql=True)
        .with_output_types(LocationRow)
    | DataframeTransform(lambda df: df)
    | WriteToBigQuery(
        schema='h3_index:STRING',
        table=OUTPUT_TABLE))
```

Running this with `DirectRunner` (or `DataflowRunner`) crashes with the following:

```
message: 'Error while reading data, error message: JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details. File: gs://analysis-dataflow-temp/temp/bq_load/0163282c2bbc47ba8ec368b158aefe2e/core-modules-development.analysis.fake_grid_power_price/5a1fc783-dcdc-44bd-9855-faea6151574f'
```

So, I looked into that file and it's just a json list per line:

```
$ cat 5a1fc783-dcdc-44bd-9855-faea6151574f
["8800459aedfffff"]
["88004536c5fffff"]
["8800418237fffff"]
["8800422b39fffff"]
["8800432451fffff"]
["88004175d7fffff"]
...
```

I figured out that BigQuery is expecting an object per line (like `{"h3_index": "88004175d7fffff"}`), and if I remove the `DataframeTransform` in the pipeline it works. So I tried using print to figure out what's happening, and changed the pipeline to this:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
  (pipeline 
    | ReadFromBigQuery(
        query=f'SELECT h3_index FROM {H3_INDEX_TABLE} LIMIT 5', use_standard_sql=True)
        .with_output_types(LocationRow)
    | DataframeTransform(lambda df: df)
    | beam.Map(print)
```

Which gives this output:

```
BeamSchema_574444a4_ae3e_4bb2_9cca_4867670ef2bb(h3_index='8806b00819fffff')
BeamSchema_574444a4_ae3e_4bb2_9cca_4867670ef2bb(h3_index='8806ab98d3fffff')
BeamSchema_574444a4_ae3e_4bb2_9cca_4867670ef2bb(h3_index='8806accd45fffff')
BeamSchema_574444a4_ae3e_4bb2_9cca_4867670ef2bb(h3_index='8806ac60a7fffff')
BeamSchema_574444a4_ae3e_4bb2_9cca_4867670ef2bb(h3_index='8806acb409fffff')
```

If I remove the `DataframeTransform` and keep the `Map(print)` I get this instead:

```
{'h3_index': '88012db281fffff'}
{'h3_index': '88012ea527fffff'}
{'h3_index': '88012e38c5fffff'}
{'h3_index': '88012e2135fffff'}
{'h3_index': '88012ea949fffff'}
```

So it looks like the `DataframeTransform` is returning collections of NamedTuples (or similar) rather than dictionaries, and the `WriteToBigQuery` fails with these tuples. I can fix it by adding a `Map` after the `DataframeTransform` to change this explicitly:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as pipeline:
  (pipeline 
    | ReadFromBigQuery(
        query=f'SELECT h3_index FROM {H3_INDEX_TABLE} LIMIT 100', use_standard_sql=True)
        .with_output_types(LocationRow)
    | DataframeTransform(lambda df: df)
    | beam.Map(lambda row: {'h3_index': row.h3_index})
    | WriteToBigQuery(
        schema='h3_index:STRING',
        table=OUTPUT_TABLE))
```

But this feels unnecessary, and I don't really understand what's happening here. What's the difference between a collection of tuples and one of dictionaries? Hoping a Beam expert can shed some light on this!

Comment: Why do you need using DataframeTransform ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DataframeTransform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) allows using the `Dataframe` api and returns a `Beam` schema.

Unfortunately if you need to manipulate a `Dict` after this step, you have to add a transformation after in order to map the `Beam` schema to a `Dict` as you shown in your question.

It can be interesting sometimes to use the `Dataframe` api and its powerful syntaxe, example :

```py
from apache_beam.dataframe.transforms import DataframeTransform

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  ...
  | beam.Select(DOLocationID=lambda line: int(..),
                passenger_count=lambda line: int(..))
  | DataframeTransform(lambda df: df.groupby('DOLocationID').sum())
  | beam.Map(lambda row: f"{row.DOLocationID},{row.passenger_count}")
```

But to be able to interact with many native `Beam` IOs like `WriteToBigquery`, you have to transform your result schema to another structure (Dict or others).

If you don't want to add the transformation from `Beam` schema to `Dict` before to write data to `BigQuery`, instead of using `DataframeTransform`, you can use an usual `ParDo`/`DoFn` or `beam.Map` with a `Python` method containing your transformations + business logic and returning the result as `Dict`.

Comment: Sorry I think you've missed the point of my post. I used `lambda df: df` in order to create a minimal example that demonstrates my issue. In my real code the `DataframeTransform` is where my business logic sits, and the table I output to has a different set of columns than the input table.

Comment: Sorry I changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks. "Beam schema" seems to be what I was looking for to understand the objects that the `DataframeTransform` was returning. The cleanest looking way I've found to map it to a dict that `WriteToBigQuery` is expecting is to use `beam.Map(lambda row: row._asdict())`.